# scroll to bottom using ref doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have no clue why my `scroll to bottom` using ref doesn't work with my below code

```
class myComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('test') // it did triggered
        this.container.scrollTop = -312
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="Panel">
                <div ref={elem => this.container = elem}>
                   {/*... list */}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My Panel is not equal to window height, imagine a dashboard app where it's wrapped at the right content area, but why isn't my scrollTop work in this case? componentDidMount did trigger.

Comment: Is `this.container` defined? Can it scroll? What is the container?

Comment: AFAIK scrollTop can't be negative.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `scrollTop` cannot be negative. Its value determines the distance scrolled from the top of the element. By default the top of the elements are displayed, and as such it doesn't make sense to have a negative scroll.

Other than that, your code should work fine.

---

Check the demo below, it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the `<ul>`:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul ref={elem => this.container = elem}>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
ul {max-height: 110px;overflow: auto;}
li {height: 100px;background: #ffaaaa;}
li:nth-child(2) {background: #aaffaa;}
li:nth-child(3) {background: #aaaaff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: if my list is props from parent component, will your solution still work? I tried `this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight`, nothing happens.

Comment: @CeldricKang, can you scroll the container yourself (e.g with your mouse)? Try console logging `this.container.scrollHeight`. If you get `0` then you cannot scroll it as it is and would have to apply some css rules to do so. Let me know.